# PHP's mixed type vs Typescript's any

Tags: php, php-7, type-systems, typing

I was trying out PHP's `mixed` type in a custom function, but this error has me stumped (punctuation is mine):

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to *<functionName>()* must be an instance of `mixed`, `string` given.

Below some (sample) code below that causes the error message and illustrates what I was hoping to achieve. Below that some TLDR with further explanation. But basicall I saw `mixed` as the type of parameters of some of PHP's native functions (for example the [is_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php) function) and wanted to do the same in a custom function.

How can I explicitly specify that a function parameter is multitype/mixed/any?

### Code

```
<?php
    function echoMixed(mixed $input) {
        if (!is_array($input)) {
            echo mixed;
        } else {
            // For arrays echo each element using recursive call.
            foreach($input as $current) {
                echoMixed($current);
            }
        }
    }
    echoMixed('test'); // <-- This results in the error.
    echoMixed(['test1', 'test2']);
?>
```

### TLDR

I'm pretty new to PHP, but was trying out the 'new' explicit type system. I'm using PHP 7.x but I think this was introduced in PHP 5.0. I love the system of optional typing of the TypeScript language, and initially assumed `mixed` works the same was as the type [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) in TypeScript. The [PHP documentation on mixed](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php) only strengthened this assumption because it states:

> *mixed* indicates that a parameter may accept multiple (but not necessarily all) types.

But after receiving this error it seems as though `mixed` is something completely different. Is this intended for arrays with values of mixed type or something?

Comment: In the second line of the function, I think you mean: `if (!is_array($input)) {`.

Answer (score 13):

To achieve what you want you just have to leave out `mixed` and not specify a typehint. PHP does **NOT** have a language keyword to explicitly specify an argument can be different types.

Note that `mixed` IS named a keyword in the documentation, but it is not a 'language keyword', but a keyword only within the PHPDocs. The same goes for `array|object`, `number`, `void`, and the other pseudo-types. Actual types that you can use in code are named `primitives` in PHP, see the below excerpts from documentation.

---

## Allowed typehints in PHP code

Here are the allowed types and the minimum PHP version to use them:

> **Class/interface name** -    *PHP 5.0.0*
>
> **self** -    *PHP 5.0.0*
>
> **array** -   *PHP 5.1.0*
>
> **callable** -    *PHP 5.4.0*
>
> **bool** -    *PHP 7.0.0*
>
> **float** -   *PHP 7.0.0*
>
> **int** - *PHP 7.0.0*
>
> **string** -  *PHP 7.0.0*
>
> **mixed** -  *PHP 8.0.0*
>
> **static** -  *PHP 8.0.0* (for return type only)

PHP 8.0 also introduces union types with the following syntax : `bool|string` which will allow booleans or strings. ([rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2))

**Warning**: `integer` and `boolean` cannot be used as typehints

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

---

## Allowed types in PHPdoc comments

PHP primitive types

> **string** A piece of text of an unspecified length.
>
> **int or integer** A whole number that may be either positive or negative.
>
> **float** A real, or decimal, number that may be either positive or negative.
>
> **bool or boolean** A variable that can only contain the state ‘true’ or ‘false’.
>
> **array** A collection of variables of unknown type. It is possible to specify the types of array members, see the chapter on arrays for more
> information.
>
> **resource** A file handler or other system resource as described in the PHP manual.
>
> **null** The value contained, or returned, is literally null. This type is not to be confused with void, which is the total absence of a
> variable or value (usually used with the @return tag).
>
> **callable** A function or method that can be passed by a variable, see the PHP manual for more information on callables.

Keywords (non native to PHP)

> **mixed** A value with this type can be literally anything; the author of the documentation is unable to predict which type it will be.
>
> **void** This is not the value that you are looking for. The tag associated with this type does not intentionally return anything.
> Anything returned by the associated element is incidental and not to
> be relied on.
>
> **object** An object of any class is returned,
>
> **false or true** An explicit boolean value is returned; usually used when a method returns ‘false’ or something of consequence.
>
> **self** An object of the class where this type was used, if inherited it will still represent the class where it was originally defined.
>
> **static** An object of the class where this value was consumed, if inherited it will represent the child class. (see late static binding
> in the PHP manual).
>
> **$this** This exact object instance, usually used to denote a fluent interface.

Source:
https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html#primitives

**Update 2021**

`mixed` type has been introduced in [PHP8](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php)
`static` type has been introduced in [PHP8](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php)

Comment: Just to add... untyped php variables in the function are already "mixed".

Comment: Thanks @Crozet! I had actually read 'pseudo-types'. I'll ask if the PHP documentation guys can add a short explanation of pseudo-types.
For instance in CSS pseudo-elements, aren't actual elements, but are still language constructs / keywords. And for instance another pseudo-type `array|object` could be used as an actual type specification in TypeScript ([Union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)). To parafrase Arthur C .Clarke: "Any sufficiently high level programming language is indistinguisable from a specification." :P

Comment: I don't like the way it's implemented in php. I want to create a strict library, where everything should become a type hint (my IDE should be able to warn me, if I did not specify a type). Sometimes I need `mixed`. If I simply leave out the type here, my IDE has no idea, if this is intended or not. So it can never warn me. Is there any discussion on php side I might not know about?

Comment: It's a very bad sign for the future of the language that this behavior was introduced in PHP. I don't know the rationale of making "mixed" a strict type when it's whole purpose was to indicate that a "mix of types" is expected. 
I can only imagine  how many projects that bufeature must have broken